# Best practices for centralized identity/auth for multiple internal applications

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

We have about 10 internal .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET 5 MVC web applications, all using Windows auth with hard-coded permissions based on AD groups. Some extend roles and permissions to the database, but each project have their own scheme.

I’m trying to move to a centralized identity database that all applications can talk to, as well as claims-based permissions (CanEditThing instead of wrapping in User.IsInRole(“Marketing”)). A benefit of this is to keep Active Directory data synchronized in one location instead of putting the same slow DirectorySearcher boilerplate code in each application, as well as quickly generate reports for Auditors showing who has been authorized access to what application.

What is the best or standard way to handle this? All applications share a central Users/Permissions database via common connection string? Or, authenticate users via IdentityServer and JWT combo and keep individual permissions confined to the individual application’s db? Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks for your insight!